# python convert sql result to tree hierarchy

Tags: python, iteration

i have a sql query that returns 3 levels of a data chain on each row (ie. Country, County, City). There may be more than 1 county per country and more than 1 city per county.

resultset:
    "UK" "Lancashire" "Burnley"
    "UK" "Lancashire" "Blackburn"
    "UK" "Merseyside" "Liverpool"
    "UK" "West Yorkshire" "Leeds"
    "UK" "West Yorkshire" "York"

how do i iterate the resultset in python to create something like:

```
UK
->Lancashire
->->Burnley
->->Blackburn
->Merseyside
->->Liverpool
->West Yorkshre
->->Leeds
->->York
```

in php i would do something like:

```
while($row = $rec->fetch_object()) {
    $var[$row->country]['county'][$row->county]['city'][$row->city] = $row->city;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a better clue as to what the table structure is.  The PHP code isn't the ideal way to show a SQL table structure.

Comment: the table structure is complex as it uses 3 INNER JOIN's and I didn't really want to explain all the relationships, hence the simplified question. Its not even geographic but i used areas as they are easy to relate to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't ideal because it's kind of obscure.

```
ccc = defaultdict( lambda: defaultdict( list ) )
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    country, county, city = row
    ccc[country][county].append(city)
```

There are probably cleaner ways to do this.

Comment: i would tick this but i have no idea what lambda does - and I have tried to understand it. +1 anyways.

Comment: @khany: Don't understand lambda?  Step 1. **search**.  It's been asked here.  Step 2.  **search**.  There are long essays available on Google.  Step 3.  **try it**.  It's pretty clear how it works and you can play with code in Python to see how things work.